# Airflow : How to schedule a dag at different times?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to schedule a dag daily, but at different times in the day, for instance :

- monday at 16H
- tuesday at 9H
- wednesday at 10H
- ...
- monday at 15H
- tuesday at 12H
- etc...

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Its pretty obvious you cannot achieve adhoc scheduling with the 'schedule_interval'. Do you have pattern that you can encode in a cron expression?

Comment: Actually I want to trigger the dag at a random hour once per day, that can't be expressed with a cron expression.

Comment: then Its pretty obvious you cannot achieve adhoc scheduling with the 'schedule_interval'. I recommend that you update the question to provide more details.

Comment: In the question I don't ask specifically to use the schedule_interval.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the dag to be scheduled randomly once a day, write python helper code.
In your dag code right before you define your dag, put a seeded random (that doesn't change with date) to create a pseudo rand.

In this example, I've converted the full date to numerical date but you can use whatever method you prefer.

Something Like the below code should work.

```
random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))
dag=Dag('TestDag,schedule_interval=randomCronString,default_args=args, catchup=False)
```

**Edit**

Airflow runs the dag every 5 seconds but by using a seeded random, you're forcing the random to only change when the seed changes (in this case when the day flips over), keep in mind though, in most systems airflow is on UTC.

If you run the following code block over and over

```
import random
import datetime

random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))
print(randomCronString)
```

You get the following results

```
random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))

print(randomCronString)
* 1 * * *

random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))
print(randomCronString)
* 1 * * *

random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))
print(randomCronString)
* 1 * * *

random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))
print(randomCronString)
* 1 * * *

random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))
print(randomCronString)
* 1 * * *

random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))
print(randomCronString)
* 1 * * *

random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))
print(randomCronString)
* 1 * * *

random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))
print(randomCronString)
* 1 * * *

random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))
print(randomCronString)
* 1 * * *

random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))
print(randomCronString)
* 1 * * *

random.seed(int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')))    
randomCronString="* {} * * *".format(random.randint(0,24))
print(randomCronString)
* 1 * * *
```

Comment: This won't work, as this script is run around every 5s by airflow, I can have a value of 12, then later a value of 13, so the job will run twice a day.

Comment: Not quite.... that's why you're using a seeded random. It's a pretty hacky solution but look at my edit.

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a delay-step (with randomized sleep interval), and schedule it before actually doing something?

E.g.

```
def _delay_dag():
    import random
    import time
    delay_by = random.randint(0,60*60*6) #e.g. to delay up to 6h from schedule time
    print(f'Delaying start by {delay_by} seconds..')
    time.sleep(delay_by)
    return True

def _do_something(ti, *kwargs):
    pass
    
with DAG('my_DAG_with_random_start', 
         schedule_interval='@daily', 
         tags=['test','random_start'],
         default_args=default_args) as dag:
    
    delay_dag = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'delay_dag',
        python_callable=_delay_dag
    )

    do_something = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'do_something',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=_do_something
    )
    
    delay_dag >> do_something
```

Comment: this should work but I'll have in my monitoring that the job lasted several hours although it really ran for a few minutes so the monitoring would be unusable.

Comment: Yes this is true, for the built-in monitoring. In case you have your own monitoring (by querying the Airflow DB) you can of course filter out the delay_dag.